# Перестала открываться карта в Хром

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Сегодня перестала открываться в обновленных браузерах карта в т.ч. в Хроме v. 70.0.3538.110
В чем может быть причина не в ключе api[image: введите сюда описание изображения] ли?

Добавляю скрин страницы с ответом сервера
[image: Добавляю скрин страницы с ответом сервера]

Comment: Приведите код вашей карты.

Comment: Почистите кэш браузера, если не поможет напишите ссылку на страницу, где возникают ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Первая ошибка в консоли показывает, что API Яндекс.Карт вызывается минимум дважды и api-ключ не указан. Начинать копать в таких случаях стоит с кода.

Лишние вызовы API без ключа стоит убрать, иначе ряд методов, а то и вся карта могут перестать работать. Строки кода, опирающиеся на ответ таких методов будут возвращать ошибку.